# How to get Title , Description , Image from Json Server using Volley

Tags: android, json, listview, android-fragments

i have got data from Json Server in ListView its Displayed in Fragment
but when i click each row in ListView , it will Open a new Blank Activity but i want to display that ListView each Row data like Title , Description and image in that Blank activity ? then how to get it in that Activity(Blank Activity) from Fragment ListView ???
i pass the data from intent method but not getting??
this is News_Fragment of NewsAdapter

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<News> newsList;
private Context context;


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title;
    public ImageView image,nextArrowimage;
    public TextView desc;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.News_title);
        image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.News_imageView);
        nextArrowimage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.news_NextArrow);
        desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.News_desc);
    }
}


public NewsAdapter(List<News> newsList,Context context) {
    this.newsList = newsList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.news_list_row, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final News news = newsList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(news.getTitle());
    //holder.image.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(news.getImage()));
    context = holder.image.getContext();
    holder.nextArrowimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.nextbutton);

    //Picasso.with(context).load("https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/advertise.png").resize(100,100).into(holder.image);

    Picasso.with(context).load("http://bitstobyte.in/upload/"+news.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_favorite_white_24dp).error(R.drawable.ic_map_24dp).resize(100,100).into(holder.image);
    //Picasso.with(context).load("http://bitstobyte.in/upload/"+ news.getImage()).resize(100,100).into(holder.image);

    holder.desc.setText(news.getDesc().trim());


    holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           TextView  title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.News_title);
            TextView desc = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.News_desc);

            String str = title.getEditableText().toString().trim();

            Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), News_Activity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
            intent.putExtra(str,"title");

            Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked " + newsList.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return newsList.size();
}
```

}

Comment: So when an item is selected from the ListView, you start another activity which holds fragments?

Comment: Pass the data in the `Intent`.

Comment: how to pass the data in the Intent?? plz give me full Explanation or Example code

Comment: show your code for passing from fragment to activity

Comment: i have post the NewsAdapter code once see above code

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to send data from one activity to another

```
    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),YourActivity.class).putExtra("Title","TileValue").putExtra("Decscription","decriptionValue));
```

and then you can retrieve in later activity like this:

```
String title=getIntent().getStringExtra("Title");
```